# Is there a way to refresh main wizard in JFace?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt, jface

I am creating an Eclipse plugin. I have initialize a wizard and added 1 page to addPages() function. When I click custom plugin, wizard opens as in snapshot.
[image]

My requirement is to add a 2nd page dynamically on clicking Add Page button and refresh window so that it would display NEXT and back button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In your class extending `Wizard` add all the pages to the wizard in the `addPages` method.

Also override the `Wizard`

```java
public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage page)
```

method. Add the logic to determine if the second page should be shown in to your `getNextPage` method.

When you want to change wizard buttons call

```java
getContainer().updateButtons();
```

You can do this in a `WizardPage` or the `Wizard`.